# Why the Facebook login popup opened on an external web browser app on my android device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Facebook login doesn't work on my android app.

I am using below Facebook SDK function.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS)
```

The web browser is opened and I faced the below screen by this upper line.

[image]

Sorry for Korean, the text means
`You have previously logged into the X app with Facebook. Would you like to keep this right?`

If I clicked `continue/agree`, there is nothing!
Just white screen...

But Actually, it works on another device!
I have two phones, and one works fine, but the other doesn't work!

The difference is web view.

1. Normal Case
   The Facebook screen is opened on an internal web view.
2. Abnormal Case
   The Facebook screen is opened on an external web browser app (Chrome)

I think that my app's callback is not called after the Facebook Login process.
Because it was processed on another app (Chrome).
If it was processed on an internal web view, it may work.

But I don't know how can I control it...

Comment: The two phones what are their api levels and which one is working out of the two?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this on Kotlin its working fine but you have Facebook app already installed at your device

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.DIALOG_ONLY
```